# SMS as Chatting technique in Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml, sms

I've to develop an android application that allows user to chat with other people via SMS and hiding mobile number of them just showing the names of them,

actually I found a code for sending  and receiving SMS, and I modified/tested them they work well,  **but I don't know** how can I integrate these codes in one activity and showing the SMS messages as in chatting application (when the sender clicks SendButton the message should moving up as in whattsapp) I don't know from where should I start !

also, the SMS message should be received in the application not to the in Box message !

any suggestions ???
thanks alot,

Answer (score 0):

Every send SMS is inserted to SMS. What you can do is remove send SMS from database so they wont be shown in user SMS app.